# MySQL: Merging two tables together with no common id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of child ids and a table of parent ids. These are separate tables. I want to create a combined child and parent table that joins them together. The 2 tables do not have a common id.

```
Child Table
| childId |
| 1       |
| 2       |

Parent Table
| parentId |
| 3        |
| 4        |

Combined Child and Parent Table
| childId | parentId |
| 1       | 3        |
| 2       | 4        |
```

These 2 tables are guaranteed to be the same length. (Although if you can make it work with arbitrary length, I would be happy.) The ordering of the pairs should just be the order in which MySQL displays it.

How can I get the resulting table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `INNER JOIN` and assign an id to each of your tables using `ROW_NUMBER`. See my query below:

```
 SELECT childId,parentId FROM
(SELECT
     @row_number1:=@row_number1+1 AS RowNumber1,
     childId
FROM Child, (SELECT @row_number1:=0)AS x ORDER BY childId) AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
     @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS RowNumber2,
     parentId
FROM Parent, (SELECT @row_number2:=0)AS y ORDER BY parentId) AS B
ON A.RowNumber1=B.RowNumber2
```

Comment: If you find this post helpful, at least accept it as an answer. If there is wrong please inform me also so I can check. Thanks. ^_^

Comment: What did you mean `ORDER BY val`? Is there a val to be ordered?

Comment: I see, so what you did is create a table of row number & child id pairs, and another table of row number & parent id pairs dynamically. Is there a need to run the ORDER BY? Can the ORDER BY run on the row number instead?

Comment: I'm getting an error from SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20653a/1 It's saying something like: "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: There is a need to run the ORDER BY if you're particular with Order in the result in your query and You cannot run ORDER BY on the row_number for it will lead to an error

Comment: I can't use order by on the child or parent ids. Because I need them to pair up with how MySQL naturally orders it.

Comment: I got rid of the table alias error by aliasing the row number tables. But still nothing. No results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20653a/6

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my query and it works already. try it now. ^_^